# How do you install LuaSocket on Mac OS X

Tags: lua, luasocket

How do you install luasocket on the Mac OS X correctly? I have lua 5.1.4 installed as a binary in the /usr/bin on my Mac. I am needing guidance to configure and install luasocket. Please let me know if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the most up-to-date version of LuaSocket:

```
git clone -b unstable git://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket.git
cd luasocket
make macosx
sudo make install
```

Comment: Can you provide a reference to it.. It is odd that instructions are not more clear.. I don't see anything in the official site.. http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/home.html#download. Just curious where you got this far. Also, `unstable` isnt present any more

Comment: @KarthikT Yes, at the time the question was asked the "stable" version of LuaSocket was very outdated. Now the easiest way is probably to use LuaRocks to install it (`sudo luarocks install luasocket`.

Comment: This is the first im hearing of `luarocks` thanks. It itself is a seperate brew package for OSX (for posterity). Wonder why the official site doesnt have this either

Answer (score 0):

Need to use some lua package manager to install luasocket.

the easiest way in MAC OS for my point, will be - luarocks

```
brew install luarocks
```

and then:

```
luarocks install luasocket
```

In my case after it, I can debug lua code by using luasocket connecting (in IntelliJ Idea in my case)